# To write $\int_{\Omega} f d\mu,$ do we require $f$ to be defined *everywhere* in $\Omega?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, notation

When we write the following expression :
$$\int_{\Omega} f d\mu$$
Do we require $f$ to be defined *everywhere* in $\Omega,$ or is it enough to require $f$ to be defined *$\mu$-almost everywhere* in $\Omega?$ $($i.e. $\mu\left(\left\{\omega \in \Omega : f(\omega) \text{ is not defined}\right\}\right)=0)$

I ask this question with reference to the following passage from Terence Tao's Introduction to Measure Theory.
[image]

Here the term $\int_{\Omega} \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n\right) d\mu$ is used even when $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ is defined *$\mu$-almost everywhere* in $\Omega$. Any clarification would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it would be good if you write either $X$ or $\Omega$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the typical definition of $\int_\Omega f\, d\mu$ assumes that $f$ is a measurable function on $\Omega$, so it must be defined everywhere.  For instance, Tao's Definition 1.4.37 defines the integral of a measurable function $f:X\to[0,+\infty]$, which in particular is a function on $X$ and so is defined at every point of $X$.

However, if $f$ is defined only almost everywhere, you can just extend it to be defined on all the points where it isn't and get a function which is defined everywhere to integrate.  It doesn't matter how you define it on those other points, since they are a set of measure $0$ and so do not affect the integral.  As a result, it is common to abuse notation slightly and speak of the integral of a function that is only defined almost everywhere.

Comment: "Strictly speaking, the typical definition ... assumes that $f$ is a measurable function." Really? *Strictly* strictly speaking, $f$ refers not to a function at all but to an equivalence class. But you're right that the objects in the set we put the equivalence relation on are indeed assumed to be defined everywhere.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: If you are speaking of an element of $L^1$, then you are talking about equivalence classes.  But when people first define integrals, they usually talk about genuine individual functions.

Answer (score 2):

We require $f$ to be defined $\mu$-almost everywhere in $\Omega$ (and $\mu$-measurable).

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ does not have to be defined everywhere in $\Omega$; it is enough that it is defined $\mu$-almost everywhere.

In fact, to be pedantic, what you are integrating is not really a function $f$ but an *equivalence class* of functions $\tilde{f}$ such that two functions that differ only on a set of measure zero are considered equivalent.